# Javascript Regex to match expression except another expression

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation, regexp-replace

First I am going to describe what I am trying to achieve. I want to copy paste a list of football games (as a regular user, not as a dev, so the plain text from a website, not the html from inspecting the html), therefor I have to parse the text. So on the website it looks like this:

[image]

The pasted text would look like:

> PERU\r\nLiga 2\r\nClasament Live\r\nFinal\r\nSanta Rosa\r\n\r\n0\r\n -
> \r\n3\r\n\r\nMolinos El Pirata\r\n(0 - 1)\r\n73
> \r\nChavelines\r\n\r\n1\r\n - \r\n0\r\n\r\nDeportivo Coopsol\r\n(1 -
> 0)\r\n20:30\r\nComerciantes Unidos\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nJuan
> Aurich\r\n22:45\r\nSantos
> FC\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nHuaral\r\nPOLONIA\r\nEkstraklasa\r\nClasament
> Live\r\n90+1 \r\nPogon Szczecin\r\n\r\n2\r\n - \r\n0\r\n\r\nStal
> Mielec\r\n(1 - 0)\r\nlive\r\n20:30\r\nPlock\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nGornik
> Z.\r\nPORTUGALIA\r\nPrimeira
> Liga\r\nClasament\r\n21:15\r\nFarense\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nMaritimo

And what I need is then to build something like this:

```
Final     Santa Rosa            0 - 3  Molinos El Pirata
75        Chavelines            1 - 0  Deportivo Coopsol
20:30     Comerciantes Unidos     -    Juan Aurich
22:45     Santos FC               -    Huaral
90+3      Pogon Szczecin        2 - 0  Stal Mielec
20:30     Plock                   -    Gornik Z.
21:15     Farense                 -    Maritimo
```

So the plan is to extract each individual line into an array and then put them in a table.
I am first cleaning up the text I don't need (the country names, league name, half time score:

```
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/\b[A-Z]{5,}\b/g, '['); // replace the country name (names with more than 4 letters, to avoid removing LASK, TSKA... but it will remove IRAN, ASIA - find better way) which is in capital letters with [
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/Clasament Live/g, ']');
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/Clasament/g, ']'); // replace the words Clasament with ]
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/g, ''); // remove everything between [ and ], including the square brackets
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/\(\d{1,2} - \d{1,2}\)/g, ''); // remove half time score eg (0 - 0)
```

And now I want to add the word newLine in front of every line, so that later I can just split by "newLine" and have all the independent lines in the array. And there are three scenarios for where a line starts: if the game didn't start (20:30), if the game has ended (Final) or if the game is running (eg 70). For the first two I have the following:

```
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/\d{2}:\d{2}/g, 'newLine$&'); // add the word newLine in front of the starting hours
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/Final/g, 'newLine$&'); // add the word newLine in front of the word Final (game has ended)
```

But the third one is more tricky. There can be 0-90, then with extra time 90+something (eg 90+3), and then can be two extra halves (eg 120, 120+..). So this is where I need some help. I need a regex that would match all these scenarios, but exclude others. To be more precise, I need to match the minute (1-120 and 1-120+...) but not the score or the hour (1-0, 20:30).
and I have tried all sorts of things for half a day, can't list them all here, but have tried things with ^ and with ?: and with ! and what not. I must say I am not good with regex, so probably most of the things I have tried were silly, but ok, what I have at this moment is this:

```
gamesUnformatted = gamesUnformatted.replace(/\d{1,3}[^(\d{2}:\d{2})]/g, 'newLine$&');
```

This would be just the first step, to replace any number with 1 to 3 digits, not considering the "90+4". and trying to ignore the hours, not the scores. But this is not working well, because it is adding newLine in front of every digit.
So this:

```
90+3      Pogon Szczecin        2 - 0 Stal Mielec
20:30     Plock                   - Gornik Z.
```

becomes this:

```
newLine90+newLine3      Pogon Szczecin        newLine2 - newLine0 Stal Mielec
newLinenewLine20:newLine30     Plock                   - Gornik Z.
```

instead of this (on the second row there are two newLine because one was added before to the hours, so that must be ignored):

```
newLine90+3      Pogon Szczecin        2 - 0 Stal Mielec
newLinenewLine20:30     Plock                   - Gornik Z.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the new line, you can do one more replacement to ensure the scores are in 1 line like `0-1`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/Dur5lD/4

**Pattern:** Match: `(\d{1,2})\s*-\s*(\d{1,2})`; Replacement: `$1-$2`

**Explanation:** Since I have newlines in the text, I have used `\s` to match space sequences. Used the capturing group `$1` and `$2` to get the desired output.

---

Once we have done this, adding `newline` should be straight forward.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/Dur5lD/5

**Pattern:** `^((?:Final)|(?:\d{2}:\d{2})|(?:\d{1,3}(?!\d)(?!-)))`

**Explanation:**

- Capture a group that can be one of `Final` or `hour` or `time`.
- For matching time, use [negative look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `(?!)`. It implies the time value like 70 or 120 should not be followed by `-` or another digit.

---

*Note:*

- I assumed `\r\n` as new line characters. If not we might need to replace `\s` and `^` characters in the expression with literal `\r\n`.
- Looks like your regex is not handling `PERU`, so I manually removed the line.
- After replacing `\n` with `\t` and then replacing `newLine` with `\n` yielded https://regex101.com/r/Dur5lD/6.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only thing that it took me a little time to notice on the regex test page was that at the end of the expression there is a /gm, not only /g. I didn't know why it's only replacing the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, making sense of a plain text copy is challenging. Here is a different approach to reconstruct the rows deterministically:

- remove country line
- remove half time scores
- remove 'live'
- combine scores that are split over multiple lines (real and empty scores)
- now we have a set of 4 lines that make up a row, e.g. we can avoid complex time parsing (final, 00, 00+0, 00:00, ...)
- split every 4 lines, resulting in rows that has newline delimited parts
- walk through rows to extract the time, team A, scores, team B from the parts, and create an object from the parts
- now you can walk through the resulting array of objects to display your table

```js
const input = 'PERU\r\nLiga 2\r\nClasament Live\r\nFinal\r\nSanta Rosa\r\n\r\n0\r\n - \r\n3\r\n\r\nMolinos El Pirata\r\n(0 - 1)\r\n73 \r\nChavelines\r\n\r\n1\r\n - \r\n0\r\n\r\nDeportivo Coopsol\r\n(1 - 0)\r\n20:30\r\nComerciantes Unidos\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nJuan Aurich\r\n22:45\r\nSantos FC\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nHuaral\r\nPOLONIA\r\nEkstraklasa\r\nClasament Live\r\n90+1 \r\nPogon Szczecin\r\n\r\n2\r\n - \r\n0\r\n\r\nStal Mielec\r\n(1 - 0)\r\nlive\r\n20:30\r\nPlock\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nGornik Z.\r\nPORTUGALIA\r\nPrimeira Liga\r\nClasament\r\n21:15\r\nFarense\r\n\r\n-\r\n\r\nMaritimo';

let rows = input
  .replace(/\r/g, '') // remove '\r'
  .replace(/[A-Z]{4,}([^\n]*\n){3}/g, '') // remove country line
  .replace(/\n\(\d{1,2} - \d{1,2}\)\n/g, '\n') // remove half time scores 
  .replace(/\nlive\n/g, '\n') // remove 'live' lines
  .replace(/\n\n(\d{1,2})\n *- *\n(\d{1,2})\n\n/g, '\n$1 - $2\n') // join 'n - m' scores
  .replace(/\n\n *- *\n\n/g, '\n-\n') // join '-' empty scores
  .match(/(?:^.*$\n?){1,4}/mg); // split every 4 lines
console.log('rows: ' + JSON.stringify(rows, null, ' '));

let scores = rows.map((line) => {
    let parts = line.split(/\n/);
    let obj = {
      time: parts[0],
      teamA: parts[1],
      score: parts[2],
      teamB: parts[3]
    };
    return obj
  });
console.log('scores: ' + JSON.stringify(scores, null, ' '));
```

Output:

```
rows:[
 "Final\nSanta Rosa\n0 - 3\nMolinos El Pirata\n",
 "73 \nChavelines\n1 - 0\nDeportivo Coopsol\n",
 "20:30\nComerciantes Unidos\n-\nJuan Aurich\n",
 "22:45\nSantos FC\n-\nHuaral\n",
 "90+1 \nPogon Szczecin\n2 - 0\nStal Mielec\n",
 "20:30\nPlock\n-\nGornik Z.\n",
 "21:15\nFarense\n-\nMaritimo"
]
scores: [
 {
  "time": "Final",
  "teamA": "Santa Rosa",
  "score": "0 - 3",
  "teamB": "Molinos El Pirata"
 },
 {
  "time": "73 ",
  "teamA": "Chavelines",
  "score": "1 - 0",
  "teamB": "Deportivo Coopsol"
 },
 {
  "time": "20:30",
  "teamA": "Comerciantes Unidos",
  "score": "-",
  "teamB": "Juan Aurich"
 },
 {
  "time": "22:45",
  "teamA": "Santos FC",
  "score": "-",
  "teamB": "Huaral"
 },
 {
  "time": "90+1 ",
  "teamA": "Pogon Szczecin",
  "score": "2 - 0",
  "teamB": "Stal Mielec"
 },
 {
  "time": "20:30",
  "teamA": "Plock",
  "score": "-",
  "teamB": "Gornik Z."
 },
 {
  "time": "21:15",
  "teamA": "Farense",
  "score": "-",
  "teamB": "Maritimo"
 }
]
```

Comment: Very nice approach, I have tried it and it works perfectly. But I have accepted the other answer as it was the first and it also answered the question, how to exclude an expression. Thanks a lot!